# OpenGL Max core profile stuck at 3.3

Tags: drivers, radeon, 16.10, amd-graphics

Even if I am using Mesa 12.0.3 on my Ubuntu 16.10 OpenGL core profile version is 3.3. I have tried Padoka and Oibaf PPAs but it doesn't change core profile version. I need minimum 4.1 to play some games.

$ lspci -nn | grep VGA

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5730 / 6570M] [1002:68c0]
```

$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD REDWOOD (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-27-generic, LLVM 3.8.1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 12.0.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

From glxinfo:

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
Device: AMD REDWOOD (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-27-generic, LLVM 3.8.1) (0x68c0)
Version: 12.0.3
Accelerated: yes
Video memory: 1024MB
Unified memory: no
Preferred profile: core (0x1)
Max core profile version: 3.3
Max compat profile version: 3.0
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer here: https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#note_19

```
OpenGL 4.1 is currently only supported on CYPRESS, CAYMAN and ARUBA. All other chips are currently limited to OpenGL 3.3
```