# OpenGL version under Lubuntu 18.04(3.3) is lower then on Windows(4.1)

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, amd-graphics, opengl, amdgpu

I'm posting today about an odd occurrence I've run into. So I have a machine that was running Windows 7 and I switched it over Lubuntu 18.04LTS. I've updated to the latest(? Apparently not... maybe for my GPU?) via `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. Yet my OpenGL version reads 3.3 instead of the 4.1 I get on windows. From the glxinfo command it seems I don't have the newest version of mesa(19.0.2) while kisak's ppa for example shows 19.3.2 and oibaf shows some hash(as of writing).

I've tried this on Ubuntu 18.04LTS live disc but the output of `glxinfo` was identical and displayed OpenGL 3.3. amdgpu-pro failed to install due to deps issue.

- https://pastebin.com/9KdY9q4i - no ppa installed
- https://pastebin.com/0G8HCXvK - oibaf ppa installed
- https://pastebin.com/1B86ftD5 - `ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa` ppa installed
- https://pastebin.com/Mg35KvWZ - attempt at installing amdgpu-pro

## Lubuntu 18.04LTS

```
glxinfo | grep 'version'
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

## Windows 7

[Speccy read out of GPU openGL version(4.1) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IGxk.png)

**EDIT**: After posting this and continuing to google around, I came across this: [OpenGL Max core profile stuck at 3.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854212/opengl-max-core-profile-stuck-at-3-3) which links to https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#note_19 which reads "OpenGL 4.2 is currently only supported on CYPRESS, CAYMAN and ARUBA. All other chips are currently limited to OpenGL 3.3"... I have a JUNIPER... anything change in the 3 or so years? :p Could I achive it any other way... maybe through a VM or something with gpu passthrough(?)... I haven't looked much into it.

Comment: did you manage in the meantime? Have similar issue

Comment: @giosans I'm sorry to say there was no solution. As I mentioned in the edit, JUNIPER card which is limited to 3.3. How I fixed this was (while not the fix I'm sure you're looking for) got a used gpu to replace it.